# iphone connecting code to the 'back' button

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to connect code to a view's 'back' button that is part of a navigation controller?  That back button is automatically coded in by the nature of it being a navigation controller so I am not sure how I can connect code to it.

(I know this should be really easy but I can't seem to find it in the documentation on navigation controller.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214965/setting-action-for-back-button-in-navigation-controller/3445994#3445994

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reality you should not have a code that needs to be executed when Back button is pressed. What exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to store codes into NSUserDefaults when the back button is pressed.

Comment: You should save something as soon as corresponding control has changed, not when you press Back button.

Answer (score 1):

viewWillDisappear is where you would typically add code to execute when the back button is pressed

Comment: I am trying to update NSUserDefaults and that doesnt seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the controller was popped in viewWillDisapper, like in this example:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {
        // back button was pressed.  We know this is true because self is no longer
        // in the navigation stack.
        NSLog(@"Article done");
    }
}
```