# Disable/Enable back button from detail view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

How can I disable the back button from the detail view controller?

Comment: You can cover the Back button and intercept touches: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/14954425/236415](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14954425/236415) In a similar fashion, you could cover and hide the Back button using an image that matches a blank portion of the navigation bar.

Comment: This is not off topic, it's the first google result for how to disable the back button on iOS.

Answer (score 45):

Depending on your configuration:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

OR:

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Or, if you just want to disable the button without hiding it, you can use this.

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

Comment: I realize this is very old, but I want to disable the button without hiding it. `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=NO` does indeed hide the back button, but `self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled=NO` does not disable the back button. (Neither does `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled=NO`)

Comment: did the `self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;` ever work?

Answer (score 15):

You can use the UINavigationItem [hidesBackButton](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006933-CH3-SW14) to hide it:

```c
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Comment: I think `hidesBackButton` is a property of `UINavigationItem` rather than `UINavigationController`