# How to disable all scrolling gestures iOS

Tags: ios

I want to implement a function whereby a lock button is pressed which locks the current state of my app and prevents all scrolling and button pressing until the unlock button is pressed. I have no idea how to go about this please give me ideas and sample code! There is a similar function in the app GoodReader if anyone knows of this.

Thanks!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404856/how-to-disable-touch-input-to-all-views-except-the-top-most-view) might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like:

```
for(UIView* subview in [self.view subviews])
    if(subview != yourLockButton)
        subview.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: Hi, where should I put this code and what is it doing?

Comment: in a method. If you want to do it when you tap a button you should do this in the button's action. The method iterates over all the subviews and disables the user interaction in them, except in the lockbutton

Comment: @Ade note that if you have an scrollview maybe you also should iterate its subviews

Comment: where you wrote "yourLockButton" what do I write. I have made a IBAction for the lock button pressed called "lockButton" but do I need to make an IBOutlet and write this here or what? Thanks

Comment: I created a property and it works! Thankyou very much!

Comment: Maybe you could help me with the next part instead of me posting another question. How do I change the lock button to an unlock button once the app is locked? rather than have two separate buttons

Comment: @Ade sorry, i couldnt connect before. 
About yourLockButton, its the name of the instance of the button.
About changing the button, its easy, you only have to change its text (if you have an image that you wanna change, change it too). If i dont remember bad, this code should be fine for that: [yourLockButton setTitle:@"new text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

You should also put a flag var to switch between user interaction and button text

Comment: o Pi I have included that code and it changes the text. However I want to change it to "Unlock" but it seems it is too long to fit because it comes up as "..." when I launch the app but "Hi" seems to show up fine. Also where would I now put the code that will unlock the locked subviews once the "Unlock" is pressed? Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Ade you can use the same method for both actions. For example, if the text of the button is "lock" you'll set the user interaction to no and change the text to unlock. If the button text is "unlock" you'll set uset interaction to yes and change the text to lock.
De nada ;)

Comment: I cannot do mylockbutton.text though, it gives an error 'Property 'text' not found on object of type UIButton *'

Comment: please bear in mind i am using UIBarButtonItems on some views for the lock button so I can use .title instead of .text but forState:UIControlStateNormal gives an error and if i take it out the function doesnt work :(

Comment: @Ade dont need the state

Comment: I also have a UINavigationBar with some custom buttons and the default "back" button. How can I disable these too?     self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled = NO; does not work?

Comment: @Adedayo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123014/ios-disable-enable-back-button-from-detail-view

Answer (score 0):

Disable all the scroll in the view

```
 - (void)disableScrollView
{
    for (UIScrollView *view in your_viewController.subviews) {

        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {

            view.scrollEnabled = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not have or want a UIScrollView, just a UIViewController