# Back button notification?

Tags: iphone, ios

in my iPhone application I need to check that user has clicked back button in Navigation controller. I think that I should get this in following method:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

}
```

I don't want to override back button event.
How can I get information that use click back button and navigation stack has changed?

**Update**
Is it possible to know that in viewDidAppear method?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method described in this answer : 
[Setting action for back button in navigation controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214965/setting-action-for-back-button-in-navigation-controller/3445994#3445994)

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {
       // back button was pressed.  We know this is true because self is no longer
       // in the navigation stack.  
    }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Hope this helps,
Vincent