# animate iphone screen on clicking back button

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, back, quartz-core

I am creating iPhone app where onclicking button I am going to another view controller with animation. below is what I have.

```
- (IBAction)booking:(id)sender {

    WebDetailsViewController *secondView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"webDetailsEnglish"];

    secondView.fileType = @"web";
    secondView.myTitle  = @"Booking";
    secondView.fileName = @"http://almaktab.com/forms/flight.html";

    [UIView  beginAnimations: @"Showinfo"context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: secondView animated:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

I want to apply same animation effect when I click Back button on `WebDetailsViewController`.

Any idea how to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214965/setting-action-for-back-button-in-navigation-controller) below did trick...

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {
        [UIView  beginAnimations: @"Showinfo"context: nil];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Thanks for all help...