# UINavigationController back button return to FIrstTableViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

So I was create three `UITableViewControllers` with `UINavigationController`. I want a back button on 3rd `UITableViewController`, what returns my view to first `UITableViewController` instead of second.
How can I do that? That must be a real `backButton`, not a image or something else. Will be perfect to do this only with storyboard.

**UPDATE**
Perhaps I poorly explained what I want.
I don't want use any button with action on it. I just want something like as setting "address" of 1st TableViewController on my default back button. There is any way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to handle "back" navigation button action in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824186/trying-to-handle-back-navigation-button-action-in-ios)

Comment: Kumar KL, in this case we got back button with wrong title what pointed on 2nd viewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to resolve my problem. Thanks for your answers guys, they was very helpful.
So for resolve this problem you just need use [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824186/trying-to-handle-back-navigation-button-action-in-ios) what give me Kumar KL upper, and wrote next method in your `UITableVIewController`

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {
       // Navigation button was pressed. Do some stuff 
      [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Now you got a `backButton` what redirect you to your viewController, BUT title of this button is wrong. Let's resolve that unfair. 
Create new class `CustomSegue`црфе inherited from `UIStoryboardSegue` with next code in `CustomSegue.m` :

```
- (void)perform
{
    UIViewController *sourceView = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destinationView = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;
    [[destinationView navigationItem] setTitle:@"TitleOfYourViewController" ] ;
    [sourceView.navigationItem setTitle:@"TitleOfButton"] ;
    [sourceView.navigationController pushViewController:destinationView animated:YES];
}
```

Now you can go to storyboard and connect 2nd ViewController with 3rd with `custom` segue.
Like you see `UINavigationController` uses Title of previous `ViewController` for button title, so you just need change it.

Answer (score 0):

add a button and connect it to following action

```
  - (IBAction)backToFirstView:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        (or)
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:yourFirstViewControllerObject animated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to navigate from DetailViewController to other view controllers.
We will go through the cases one by one.

- First of all I would like to clear that if its your default
  navigation bar's back button, then it must return to the last most
  view controller only which is actually a default behavior of a
  navigation controller.
- Second, If you would like to go back to the
  last most view controller on the tap of a button placed by you, you
  should write the following code

> ```
>    [self.navigationController popToViewController:NAME_OF_A_VIEWCONTROLLER animated:YES];
> ```

- Third, If you would like to go to the first view controller from where you
  started, you should write the following code

  `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`