# What is the right way to go back a performed segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

Basically I have a view controller that pushes to the next view controller with `[self performSegueWithIdentifier: sender:];` and in the `prepareForSegue` I wanted to change the VC's title to "Back" so that in the next VC the back bar button item will be "Back" instead of the initial VC's title.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    self.title = @"Back";

}
```

[image]

Now the problem is that when I return back to the first VC by tapping on the Back button, I have to change the title back to the initial title or else the title will stay as "Back".

If only there was a method like `prepareForSegue` so that I can get the destination VC and change it's title...

Another example is that I have a storyboard of 3 view controllers like so:

[image]

I've hidden the navigation controller to use my own button to go back the segue. While this way works, but it seems rather odd that I have to add 2 more segues just to return back to the first VC...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your storyboard, drag a **Navigation Item** onto your first view controller. Set the **Title** to your view controller's title, and **Back Button** To "Back"

[image]

Alternatively, to do this programatically, create a `UIBarButtonItem` with nil action and target, and assign to `navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` (make sure you do this in the view controller you are coming *from*)

Comment: Brilliant! I was searching all over stackoverflow and tried answers like "do this in `viewDidLoad` etc." and I can't believe it was THAT simple. One question however, is there a way I can do an action (Like alert "Are you sure to go back?") when the back button is tapped?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to intercept the back button. The closest you'll get is adding a custom `leftBarButtonItem` to the child view controller, hooking up to an `IBAction`, then presenting the alert from there

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Saw this question here and did the button implementation instead.. Much thanks anyway! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824186/trying-to-handle-back-navigation-button-action-in-ios

Answer (score -1):

in the method`prepareForSegue:`, you can get the `destinationViewController` by `segue.destinationViewController`. i think this is what you want.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. Theres no segue indicating to go back to the previous VC. I tried using the same segue (The one that navigates forward) and when I tapped on the back, it's not firing up my action. `if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"oneMinChallenge"]) {//action}`