# Handle Back button NavigationController to push to another ViewController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, pushviewcontroller, backbarbuttonitem

im currently working on a flow like this: First after i pressed the Login Button on LoginVC -> Push to WebViewVC -> Press Back Button on NavigationBar -> Push to a TabbarVC with also contain the webViewVC, i mean webViewVC is a tab of TabbarVC. So I wonder how can i handle the Back button in order to push to the TabbarVC, not comeback to the LoginVC. Here i would attach my screen flow:

[image]

The top left one is the WebViewVC. Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to handle "back" navigation button action in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824186/trying-to-handle-back-navigation-button-action-in-ios)

Comment: I assume there is a confusion, why do you want to take to saparate webviewVC even it is a tab of tabbarcontroller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add this code in the webViewVc (not the one in the tabBar). Call addBackButton in ViewDidLoad**

Note: You will need to change the image to one that you have in your assets and change the name of the TabBarVc to the one you have.

```
func addBackButton(_ viewController: UIViewController)
    {
        let backButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Icon_back"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.goToTabBar))

        self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(backButton, animated: true)
    }

func goToTabBar()
    {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        self.navigationController?.present(TabBarVC(), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```