# How to reset ViewController on the press of a button in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

My app has a ViewController consisting multiple textfield and custom UI elements arranged as a form with "submit" and "reset" buttons.

I want to reset all the textfields and custom UI elements when user clicks the submit button so that user gets a feeling that same Form is opened again.

I tried calling ViewDidLoad() and setNeedsDisplay() on the click of "Submit" button but data previously filled by user remains as it is.

Kindly Help!

Comment: Never call `viewDidLoad` or other lifecycle methods directly.

Comment: Added my answer below. It might help you.  @ujjwal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the text of all textfields to an empty string (the `text` value). There is no magic function to clean everything in a view.

The only other solution would be to actually display the ViewController again, but this is probably not what you want, because it causes overhead as well as you might see something of the switching on the screen.

Comment: I would prefer to display ViewController again rather clearing all text fields manually. But the problem is that, I am using navigation controller so If I will push same ViewController again then when user will click back, he will see the previous filled view. How can I pop current view controller and push same view controller again?

Comment: You can either pop the old ViewController from the navigation stack before presenting another instance of it again (using `popViewController(animated:)`) or you change the behaviour of the back button as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824186/trying-to-handle-back-navigation-button-action-in-ios)

Comment: I'd advise to just clear the text fields manually. There are IBOutletCollections, if you used the IB, so you can just iterate through the collection easily with a function. Alternatively, you could iterate through the UIViewController's subviews, check if the class is of type UITextField, and if so, reset it.

Answer (score -1):

If you programmatically coded your textfields and some other objects, you can refresh always your viewController everytime by adding all your UI codes in the  predefined method: -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{} and you should remove all self.view elements by adding this code. 
[self.view.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

You codes in the viewWillAppear will look like this.

> ```
> -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
> [self.view.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
>
> // Codes for User Interface here 
>
> }
> ```