# Navigation Bar Back Button not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, uinavigationbar

I am trying add a custom back button so that I can perform some tasks before popping the controller. But no matter how hard I tried this function bind with back button doesn't work. I am adding some code to understand

```
-(void)customizeNavigationBar
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Video Call";

   UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
              initWithTitle:@" " style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
              target:self action:@selector(didBackBtnTap)];
   [self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];
}
```

and this is the function, which is not calling at all,

```
-(void)didBackBtnTap
{
    [self popToProfileScreen];
}
```

Please suggest any solution, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let use `setLeftBarButtonItem` instead of `setBackBarButtonItem`.

Comment: I want it to look like back button but override it with my custom function .. I don't want to add any icon with it

Comment: It is working in my other controllers very well but not here

Comment: In case you want to keep default back button, it's another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824186/trying-to-handle-back-navigation-button-action-in-ios

Comment: Ok let me check it out

Answer (score 1):

Use `leftbarbutton` item instead of `setBackBarButtonItem`

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Comment: I want it to look like back button but override it with my custom function .. I don't want to add any icon with it

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `setLeftBarButtonItem` or `setBackBarButtonItem`, it will take effect on the viewController you’re pushing to but not the current one. That’s why you need to directly set the current `leftBarButtonItem`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to write your custom code in viewWillDisappear.

Comment: No I cannot use in this method.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15);
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backButtonImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
backButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -10, 0, 0);
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
```

Add an image(15*15, @1x @2x @3x) like back button of NavigationBar in xcasstes *backButtonImage*

```
- (void)backButtonPressed {}
```