# How to show Back and Done button on CNContactViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cncontactviewcontroller

I create new `CNContactViewController` for add new contacts on phone directory but when I navigate to controller `CNContactViewController` navigation back button is hidden. Following my code.

```
    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
    CNMutableContact *contact = [[CNMutableContact alloc] init];
    contact.familyName = @"name_1";
    contact.givenName = @"xyz";

    CNLabeledValue *homePhone = [CNLabeledValue 
    labeledValueWithLabel:CNLabelHome value:[CNPhoneNumber 
    phoneNumberWithStringValue:@"0123456789"]];
    contact.phoneNumbers = @[homePhone];

    CNContactViewController *contactVC = [CNContactViewController 
    viewControllerForNewContact:contact];
    contactVC.contactStore = store;
    contactVC.delegate = (id)self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:contactVC animated:TRUE];
```

Please suggest me best solution for showing back & Done button using Objective-C or Swift-3.

Comment: @EricAya thank you, i will also change my suggestion on description.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a `UINavigationViewController` to wrap your viewControllers in.

This way you can use segues (lookup: `push and popViewControllerAnimated`) to navigate between them. You can add `UIBarbuttonItem` to the `UINavigationBar`. It even has its own built in back button.

I suggest you look up the marked classes/actions.

Comment: Are you working with the storyboard? If yes, is it possible that you can show me a screenshot on which i can clearly see your viewcontrollers?

Comment: i used this with programetically

Comment: Well, I don't have much info but maybe you could try these options:

1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/27127546/7018180

2) Create a navigation bar in your viewcontroller and add your own barbuttons to it:

`UINavigationBar *navbar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
 //do something like background color, title, etc you self
[self.view addSubview:navbar];`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75123429/634958), you can subclass `CNContactViewController` to add a `done` button to the `navigationItem`.

Something like this:

```
import ContactsUI

class ContactDetailsViewController: CNContactViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        updateNavigationItem()
    }

    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

        updateNavigationItem()
    }

    private func updateNavigationItem() {
        if !isEditing {
            // add a 0.5 seconds delay to add button after the editing animation finishes
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = .init(
                    barButtonSystemItem: .done,
                    target: self,
                    action: #selector(self.doneTapped)
                )
            }
        }
    }

    @objc private func doneTapped() {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

In order to make use of this class, make sure that `ContactDetailsViewController` is embedded inside a `UINavigationController`.

Although I'm so late to answer, but I hope this helps you or someone else.

Comment: Can I implement this in Interface Builder?

Comment: @daniel i'm not sure about implementing it in IB, because I tried the above solution programmatically and it worked.