# How to set UIViewController to be shown on back button of Navigation bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have one `ViewController` with button Checkout, On tap checkout button `CartViewController` should open if user is logged in but if the user is not logged in the `LoginViewController` should open and after login `CartViewController` should open, This is working fine but my problem is when I tap on buck button of navigation bar in `CartViewController` it is showing LoginViewController if it is coming from `LoginViewController`. I want it to go back to `ViewController` every time

Comment: i have posted the answer please try it.

Comment: I wonder why someone has down-voted each and every post.

Comment: may be they don't know there -1 for them also for each downvote

Comment: @VarunNaharia - Any specific reason for Removing the answer from "Accepted" state, when you are not accepting any alternate answer?

Comment: I am removing all down vote question and answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate the `viewControllers` property of `UINavigationController` object to remove a particular object from stack. So when you are taking the route of `ViewController -> LoginViewController-> CartViewController`, then you should remove the `LoginViewController` object from the stack. That way when you pop from `CartViewController` you will be back to `ViewController`.
Check [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638372/ios-navigation-stack-manipulation) for how to manipulate navigation controller stack

Answer (score -1):

Write below code (for removing the to rootViewController) on  Navigation Back bar button Item Action:
**Code:**

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: You are assuming  it as if the ViewController is the initial point of application. What if the ViewController is not the root object in stack?

Comment: @Gandalf you are right. but i think for this question view controller it the RootViewController...

Comment: Yes i understand this will work perfectly if that is the case. But it may or may not be. I believe when things are not clear then solution should be more generic.

Comment: @Gandalf Yes. you are absolutely correct but in this question he has mention that. (if he has an view controller and doing navigation start navigation from it then it should be the Root View Controller) so as per my opinion for this question this it the perfect answer.