# Pop to another view controller in navigation controller hierarchy

Tags: objective-c

I have tree view controllers embed in navigation controller. The **first** one contains conversations, the **second** contains messages of a particular conversation. The **third** is to create new conversation.

[The view controllers structure](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0pqcowveac5rpt1/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202015-03-06%20%D0%B2%2014.42.10.png?dl=0)

When a user creates new conversation he's redirecting to **second** controller with conversations. So the question is when a users has been redirected from the **third** controller to **second** vc and taps Back button on the **second** view controller how to pop out from the **second** view controller to **first** after creating new conversation. Because the navigation controller pops user to previous controller - **third** controller new conversations.

P.S. The **first** view controller isn't root controller. There are several controllers before.

Comment: If you want Back to pop two view controllers rather than one, then you shouldn't be Pushing the  New Conversation VC in the first place, it's more like it's replacing the conversations VC than pushing on top of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting action for back button in navigation controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214965/setting-action-for-back-button-in-navigation-controller)

Comment: Seems that you need a custom action for back button. Try following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214965/setting-action-for-back-button-in-navigation-controller

Comment: I know how to create custom action for a back button. The problem is when I wrote the code that creates new view controller that is exists already in memory. And I want to return to existing view controller in navigation controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked it some time ago and now I became smarter so I can answer my own question in a really right way.

I had to use modal view controller. Thus when we want to create a new conversation we're showing the **third VC** as a modal view controller, and when the conversation is created we're delegating about this to the **first VC**. In the first view controller I'm creating the **second VC** and pushing it after that I dismissed the modal VC.

```
NewConversationViewController *vc = [NewConversationViewController new]; //any setups
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:modalVC completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like. By adding custom back button on navigationBarItem.

```
    NSArray *viewContrlls=[[self navigationController] viewControllers];
    for( int i=0;i<[ viewContrlls count];i++){
        id obj=[viewContrlls objectAtIndex:i];
        if([obj isKindOfClass:[ManageAlertsListViewController class]] ){
            [[self navigationController] popToViewController:obj animated:YES];
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: But am I creating a new view controller in this way? Or I'm returning to previous that was saved in memory?

Comment: In this you only jump to previous viewController in stack of navigationController

Comment: Great. Thank you. That's it. But when I jump to previous using this code there's no navigation bar. How to six it?

Comment: There might be something else which is disturbing your navigation. Cannot suggest any solution without having look at code.