# What is the best practice to add validation code on a Back button action in a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIViewController that is created via instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier. In that controller, the user may enter some text that I need to validate before saving. There is a back button that the user clicks and that will trigger the save. But if there is an error, I will not allow the user to go back. What is the best practice for this? I read stackoverflow and the solution seems to be overriding UINavigationController, which I think is some sort of hack. 
I cannot put the code in willMovetoParentViewController since there is no return of true or false. It will still proceed.

Comment: You have to create custom back button and set it to the UINavigationBar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use an extension.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19132881/1781087) seems to solve your problem.

Comment: Ok I guess Apple has not solved it yet. Your answer works. Thx.