# Displaying a UIAlert before dismissing the view

Tags: ios, swift

My view is being dismissed through the previous button on the navigation bar. I think the correct term for that is that the view is being popped off the view stack. Now before actually dismissing the view I want to display a UIAlert asking the user to setup his/her address.

I've tried this but the UIAlert is not being show:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    if let currentUser = ApiManager.sharedInstance.currentUser {
        if !currentUser.hasAddress {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Missing address", message: "We see you're stilling missing an address, would you like set it now?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "yes".localized, style: .Default, handler: { (alertAction) in
                let newViewController = LocationViewController()
                newViewController.delegate = self
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
            }))

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "no".localized, style: .Default, handler: nil))

            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

In my console the following gets printed:

```
2016-10-28 16:58:47.380 gaifong[17096:14515422] Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fd7037e4cb0> on <gaifong.ProfileViewController: 0x7fd7048cc000> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Comment: is your controller is presented or pushed ?

Comment: It is being pushed

Comment: Please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34343418/2172546

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `leftBarButtonItem` on navigationItem and make an action to `leftBarButtonItem` where you can handle this.

in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.goBack))

// Then handle the button selection
func goBack() {
  if let currentUser = ApiManager.sharedInstance.currentUser {
    if !currentUser.hasAddress {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Missing address", message: "We see you're stilling missing an address, would you like set it now?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "yes".localized, style: .Default, handler: { (alertAction) in
            // here you can pop to main controller
            self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "no".localized, style: .Default, handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The goBack() function doesn't get triggered when I go back. What if users swipe to go back? I need to implement another function?

Comment: it must be triggered. and  swipe to go back will won't work in that case.