# React Native with native iOS SDK - display native view and navigate to other native views

Tags: ios, react-native

So I've got a 3rd party SDK to integrate with a react native application.

To make things simple -
SDK is initialized by providing UINavigationController and returns UIViewController.
React Native app should show the view controller as subview in a specific screen.
The returned VC has some buttons - some are presenting other VCs and some are pushing other VCs.

To support this SDK I've changed default root VC of React Native to be UINavigationController.
As suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45200771/7553268

The problem -
Returned VC is displayed as expected.
Also buttons that are using present works.
But pushing other VCs are not working.

Maybe related -
I also get warning about UITableView isn't in the view hierarchy (first returned VC has table view inside) but it shows up correctly and I can interact with it.

Comment: Have you fixed this issue?

Comment: //**navigate to SDK screen**
HKSDKController.load(withMainPage: false, andParentViewController: self)

Comment: It's not navigated to the SDK page. andParentViewController: self)

Comment: andParentViewController is UIViewController