# how to determine that the navigation bar's back button has been clicked and then showing a alert

Tags: iphone

working on a game based project.i am having a view controller as GameScreen.
on the top of Gamescreen having a navigation bar with back button(default).Now if user clicks on back button i have to show alert.
so how to determine "backbutton got clicked."? 
any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your viewdidload method :

```
UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(cancel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button] autorelease];
```

In the cancel method:

```
- (IBAction) cancel:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    or show your alert view
}
```

Otherwise also you can just override the method if you do not want a custom back button.

Comment: i am trying this in viewdidLoad:-UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""];
 [addButton action:@selector(backbuttonclicked)];
 [addButton style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered];      and selector method as:-(IBAction)backbuttonclicked:(id)sender
{
 NSLog(@"back button clicked");
}  i have also declared method in .h file.what wrong i am doing.
 [addButton target:self];
 [addButton release];

Comment: You are not assigning the button to the navigation bar button

Answer (score 1):

Your `UINavigationBarDelegate` has got a nice method for that, called [shouldPopItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

You can override that in your delegate and show there the alert. This gives you also a chance to cancel the going-back (popping).

Answer (score 0):

[Stopping the self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem from exiting a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184474/stopping-the-self-navigationitem-leftbarbuttonitem-from-exiting-a-view/1812545#1812545) - here you go maddy, answers the question in a different context but same basis -